# PostgreSQL index reduces data size but makes the query slower

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, jsonb

I have a PostgreSQL table with 7.9GB of JSON data. My goal is to perform aggregations **on the whole table** on a daily basis, the aggregation results will later be used for analytical reports in Google Data Studio.

One of the queries I'm trying to run looks as follows:

```
explain analyze
select tender->>'procurementMethodType' as procurement_method,
       tender->>'status' as tender_status,
       sum(cast(tender->'value'->>'amount' as decimal)) as total_expected_value
from tenders
group by 1,2
```

The query plan and execution time are the following:

[image: Query without any indexes]

The problem is that the database has to scan through all the 7.9GB of data, even though the query uses only 3 field values out of approximately 100. So I decided to create the following index:

```
create index on tenders((tender->>'procurementMethodType'), (tender->>'status'), (cast(tender->'value'->>'amount' as decimal)))
```

The size of the index is 44MB, which is much smaller than the size of the entire table, so I expect that the query should be much faster. However, when I run the same query with the index created, I get the following result:

[image: The same query with index]

The query with index is slower! How can this be possible?

EDIT: the table itself contains two columns: the ID column and the jsonb data column:

```
create table tenders (
   id uuid primary key,
   tender jsonb
)
```

Comment: Can you include the table definition in this question?

Comment: @TheImpaler I've included the table definition in the question

Comment: Well, you are retrieving all rows, so an index isn't going to help to begin with. The second plan is an `Index Scan` which goes back and forth between the index and the table. An `Index Only Scan` would make things faster. Try `vacuum analyze tenders;` and see if that gives you an Index Only Scan. If you are on Postgres 12, extracting those three values into computed columns (no index) might be worth a try either, as that removes the need to touch the JSON value completely (effectively "normalizing" your model a bit)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . I think you should expand your comment into an answer.

Comment: After `vacuum analyze tenders` postgres just ignored the index and used the seq scan. I'm on postgres 11, so I understand that I can't do anything to speed up the query. Anyway, thank you so much for you answer

Comment: Another option would be to create a "materialized view" using the query. May be worth exploring...

Comment: @TheImpaler this is exactly what I'm going for: the results of the aggregation query will be stored for responsive dashboards. I was just wondering whether there was a way to speed up the materializing process itself

Answer (score 1):

The code that does an index only scan is somewhat deficient in this case.  It thinks it needs "tender" to be available in the index in order to fulfill the demand for `cast(tender->'value'->>'amount' as decimal)`.  It fails to realize that having `cast(tender->'value'->>'amount' as decimal)` itself in the index obviates the need for "tender" itself.  So it is doing a regular index scan, in which it has to jump from the index to the table for every row it will return, to fish out "tender" and then compute `cast(tender->'value'->>'amount' as decimal)`.  This means it is jumping all over the table doing random io, which is much slower than just reading the table sequentially and then doing a sort.

You could try an index on `((tender->>'procurementMethodType'), (tender->>'status'), tender)`.  This index would be huge (as large as the table) if it can even be built, but would take away the need for a sort.

But your current query finishes in 30 seconds.  For a query that is only run once a day, does it really *need* to be faster than this?

Comment: Well, the query doesn't _have_ to be faster. I'm just working on a proof-of-concept so I was wondering whether it _could_ be faster. By the way, now I'm facing another problem: I have changed the postgresl.conf file (boosted up the work_mem, shared_buffers, wal size, and the maximum number of workers, also changed the random page cost to 1.1 since the data are on an SSD) and now the query does not use parallel workers and runs more slowly, I don't know whether it's a topic of a separate question